# Crash when copying to Null location in C & invalid data being passed

Tags: c, memory, crash, null

i have the following structs:

```
struct PList{
    Person value;
    PList* next;
}
```

and

```
struct Person{
    char name[100];
    PersonID ID;
    float amountOwed;
}
```

and

```
struct PersonID{
    int number;
    char letter;
}
```

in the main method:

```
Person n;
// n is inputted from the user
addPersonToList(&n, &customers); //customers is a PList
```

this is the code of the addPersonToList:

```
void addPersonToList(Person* p, PList* pdb) {
        PList* db;
        db = pdb;
        while (db->next != NULL ) {
                db = db->next;
        }
        PList a;
        a = createNewPList();  // this simply assigns next to NULL and value to an empty Person
        a.value = *p;
        memcpy(db->next,&a,sizeof(PList)+sizeof(Person)+sizeof(PersonID));
}
```

here is createNewPList

```
PList createNewPList() {
        PList a;
        a.next = NULL;
        a.value = constructPerson("", constructPersonID(' ', 0), 0);
        return a;
}
```

**Problem 1**   *UNSOLVED*
when the addPersonToList method is called, all values in the Person are passed correctly except for the p->Id.number. This is mixed up completely between before the method call, and after the method call.

**Problem 2**  *SOLVED*
instead of the memcpy i tried also db->next = a; as well as assigning all values manually.
However on that line the program is crashing, I am assuming cause the db->next is currently NULL

As for errors, there are no errors displayed. The program simply crashes.

Thanks for any solution

Comment: you can't memcpy to NULL. that's just ... wrong o_o what do you even expect this to do?

Comment: `sizeof(struct PList)` inlcudes the size of all it's members and sub-members.

Comment: fixed the sizeof. What alternative is there to copying to null if i want something in there then?

Comment: Copying to `NULL` always provokes undefined behaviour. You need to somehow allocate valid memory, to copy something into.

Comment: @mangusbrother have a look into `man malloc`

Comment: **Problem N**: You need to *seriously* research how (a) pointers are used in the C language, (b) how dynamic memory allocation in C works, and (c) how to build/manage a [linked list in C](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html), of which there are about a hundred-thousand samples on the web.

Comment: @mangusbrother oh, and have a look at `man memcpy` as well. All you'll ever want to know about C can be found in manpages.

Comment: the assignign to the NULL value crash was solved. however the invalid passing of the person->ID.number is still unsolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
while (db->next != NULL )
/* ... */
memcpy(db->next
```

By definition this will always be wrong since it will always `memcpy` into `NULL`. You need to allocate stuff to `db->next`. I *suspect* all you need is to drop the `memcpy` and say:

```
db->next = createNewPList();
```

#### EDIT

After seeing more of your amazing code, you probably want:

```
db->next = malloc(...);
memcpy(db->next, &a ... );
```

Comment: *db->next = createNewPList(); results in a crash however
Added the createNewPList details

Comment: @mangusbrother Don't add the *.

Comment: `createNewPList()` does not seem to return a reference to `PList`.

Comment: Probably, `createNewPList()` should be creating nodes on the heap instead of the stack.

Comment: not adding the * results in incompatible types, whereas if i make createNewPList return a pointer to PList i'd be returning a pointer to a local variable which wouldn't work either way no?

Comment: Have `createNewPList` build a node on the heap (using `malloc`). This will give you a nice, persistent, pointer which you can return without issue (except determining who's responsible for freeing this new pointer).

Comment: converted createNewPList to return PList* using malloc. works fine now. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `createNewPList()` should return a pointer to something allocated on the heap:

```
PList*
createNewPList(void)
{
        PList*    a;

        if ((a = malloc(sizeof(*a)) == NULL)
            return NULL;
        a->next = NULL;
        a->value = constructPerson("", constructPersonID(' ', 0), 0);
        return a;
}
```

Then, you should just forget about that `memcpy()` and just set your `next` as the return value of `createNewPList()`:

```
db->next = createNewPList();
```

Do not forget to go though your `linked list` and to free every pointers when you won't need them anymore.

Comment: conditions with side effects are evil! ;)

Comment: These values will all be needed until program termination so i assume that upon closing the program the're freed automatically?

Comment: Yes, any desktop OS will handle the remaining not freed memory. However, I think it's a good habit to clean it yourself, what if someday you end up working on an obscure platform that does not handle it for some reason?

Comment: this is soley for an assignment however and that is more than is required i believe so since i won't exactly benefit in this case it's not worth the time.